# Performance of java.lang.reflect.Array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, reflection

Since I'm making heavy use of reflective access to arrays in a project, I decided to compare the performance of `array[index]` vs `java.lang.reflect.Array.get(array, index)`. While I anticipated, that reflective calls are quite a bit slower, I was surprised to see that they are between 10-16 times slower.

So I decided to write a simple utility method that does about the same as `Array#get` but receives the array at the given index by casting the object instead of using a native method (as does `Array#get`):

```
public static Object get(Object array, int index){
    Class<?> c = array.getClass();
    if (int[].class == c) {
        return ((int[])array)[index];
    } else if (float[].class == c) {
        return ((float[])array)[index];
    } else if (boolean[].class == c) {
        return ((boolean[])array)[index];
    } else if (char[].class == c) {
        return ((char[])array)[index];
    } else if (double[].class == c) {
        return ((double[])array)[index];
    } else if (long[].class == c) {
        return ((long[])array)[index];
    } else if (short[].class == c) {
        return ((short[])array)[index];
    } else if (byte[].class == c) {
        return ((byte[])array)[index];
    }
    return ((Object[])array)[index];
}
```

I believe that this method provides the same functionality as `Array#get`, with the notable difference of the thrown exceptions (e.g. a `ClassCastException` gets thrown instead of an `IllegalArgumentException`, if one calls the method with an `Object` that is no array.).

To my surprise, this utility method performs *much* better than `Array#get`.

Three questions:

1. Do others here experience the same performance issues with `Array#get`, or is this perhaps a hardware/platform/Java-version issue (I tested with Java 8 on a dual core Windows 7 laptop)?
2. Do I miss something concerning the functionality of the method `Array#get`? I.e. is there some functionality that must necessarily be implemented using a native call?
3. Is there a specific reason, why `Array#get` was implemented using native methods, when the same functionality could have been implemented in pure Java with a much higher performance?

---

**Test Classes and Results**

The tests have been done using [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/) (latest Caliper from git necessary to compile the code). But for your convenience I also included a main method that performs a simplified test (you need to remove the Caliper annotations to make it compile).

TestClass:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import com.google.caliper.BeforeExperiment;
import com.google.caliper.Benchmark;

public class ArrayAtBenchmark {

    public static final class ArrayUtil {
        public static Object get(Object array, int index){
            Class<?> c = array.getClass();
            if (int[].class == c) {
                return ((int[])array)[index];
            } else if (float[].class == c) {
                return ((float[])array)[index];
            } else if (boolean[].class == c) {
                return ((boolean[])array)[index];
            } else if (char[].class == c) {
                return ((char[])array)[index];
            } else if (double[].class == c) {
                return ((double[])array)[index];
            } else if (long[].class == c) {
                return ((long[])array)[index];
            } else if (short[].class == c) {
                return ((short[])array)[index];
            } else if (byte[].class == c) {
                return ((byte[])array)[index];
            }
            return ((Object[])array)[index];
        }
    }

    private static final int ELEMENT_SIZE = 100;
    private Object[] objectArray;

    @BeforeExperiment
    public void setup(){
        objectArray = new Object[ELEMENT_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
            objectArray[i] = new Object();
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int ObjectArray_at(int reps){
        int dummy = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ELEMENT_SIZE; j++) {
                dummy |= objectArray[j].hashCode();
            }
        }
        return dummy;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int ObjectArray_Array_get(int reps){
        int dummy = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ELEMENT_SIZE; j++) {
                dummy |= Array.get(objectArray, j).hashCode();
            }
        }
        return dummy;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int ObjectArray_ArrayUtil_get(int reps){
        int dummy = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ELEMENT_SIZE; j++) {
                dummy |= ArrayUtil.get(objectArray, j).hashCode();
            }
        }
        return dummy;
    }

    // test method to use without Cailper
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayAtBenchmark benchmark = new ArrayAtBenchmark();
        benchmark.setup();

        int warmup = 100000;
        // warm up 
        benchmark.ObjectArray_at(warmup);
        benchmark.ObjectArray_Array_get(warmup);
        benchmark.ObjectArray_ArrayUtil_get(warmup);

        int reps = 100000;

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int temp = benchmark.ObjectArray_at(reps);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        long time = (end-start)/reps;
        System.out.println("time for ObjectArray_at: " + time + " NS");

        start = System.nanoTime();
        temp |= benchmark.ObjectArray_Array_get(reps);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        time = (end-start)/reps;
        System.out.println("time for ObjectArray_Array_get: " + time + " NS");

        start = System.nanoTime();
        temp |= benchmark.ObjectArray_ArrayUtil_get(reps);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        time = (end-start)/reps;
        System.out.println("time for ObjectArray_ArrayUtil_get: " + time + " NS");
        if (temp == 0) {
            // sanity check to prevent JIT to optimize the test methods away
            System.out.println("result:" + result);
        }
    }
}
```

The Caliper results can be viewed [here](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/11b041b5-a103-4b81-a7d6-767582e2ad4f#r:scenario.benchmarkSpec.methodName).

The results of the simplified main method look like this on my machine:

```
time for ObjectArray_at: 620 NS
time for ObjectArray_Array_get: 10525 NS
time for ObjectArray_ArrayUtil_get: 1287 NS
```

---

**Additional information**

- The results are similar when running the JVM with "-server"
- The other `Array` methods (e.g. `Array#getInt`, `Array#getLength`, `Array#set` etc.) also perform much slower than similarly implemented utility methods
- This question is somewhat related to: [What is the purpose of java.lang.reflect.Array's getter and setter methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2924372/3270595)

Comment: Did you test your code with multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Just wondering: why are you using reflection at all? My suspection would be that the just-in-time compiler is very good at optimizing "raw" array accesses; and anything that goes "reflection" is poorly/not at all optimized by the JIT. But that is guessing ...

Comment: @AaronDigulla yes I did - it turns out, that multi-dimensional arrays are instances or Object[].

Comment: @Jägermeister Because I need to handle both Object arrays and primitive arrays with the same API

Comment: @Balder Just out of curiosity; can you give a small example on how your API looks like; and how it is used?

Comment: @Jägermeister Well, in the end it "looks" very similar to the utility method above - you get an Object that could either be an Object[] or a primitive array, and then the array gets handled accordingly...

Comment: Can you try your code in an array of `String`? I'm not sure the last cast will work if the array type isn't `Object`.

Comment: @AaronDigulla It also works with a String[] since it is also an instance of an Object[].

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051447 - also see the native implementation of `Array.c`: `"TODO: Performance"` ;-)

Comment: I would've genuinely expected `Arrays.get()/set()` methods to be intrinsic. But apparently they aren't. Only `getLength()` and `newArray()` are.

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks for the link! - this explains quite a bit.

Comment: @Marco13 Good note. I think you should make this an answer.

Comment: @apangin It does not directly answer questions 2. and 3. (and surprising- and unfortunately, there also have not been any discussions or statements by the implementors in this regard....)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `Array.get` is slow in OpenJDK / Oracle JDK because it is implemented by a native method and is not optimized by JIT.

There is no special reason for `Array.get` to be native except that it has been so from the earliest releases of JDK (when JVM was not so good and there was no JIT at all). Moreover, there is a pure Java [compatible implementation](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/reflect/Array-source.html) of `java.lang.reflect.Array` from GNU Classpath.

Currently (as of JDK 8u45) only [Array.newInstance](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/5755b2aee8e8/src/share/vm/opto/library_call.cpp#l3765) and [Array.getLength](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/5755b2aee8e8/src/share/vm/opto/library_call.cpp#l3827) are optimized (being JVM intrinsics). Looks like nobody really cared about performance of reflective get/set methods. But as @Marco13 [noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306160/performance-of-java-lang-reflect-array#comment48711307_30306160) there is an open issue [JDK-8051447](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8051447) to improve the performance of `Array.*` methods somewhen in future.