# Combining Java Functions without Overloading

Tags: java, function, overloading

How would I combine these two functions to make my code more efficient? I am currently just overloading the functions to allow for integers and strings to be accepted as arguments.

```
private void flushGrid(int grid[][], int replacement) {
        for(int x=0;x<grid.length;x++) {
            for(int y=0;y<grid[0].length;y++) {
                grid[x][y] = replacement;
            }
        }
    }

private void flushGrid(String grid[][], String replacement) {
    for(int x=0;x<grid.length;x++) {
        for(int y=0;y<grid[0].length;y++) {
           grid[x][y] = replacement;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You couldn't, really.

Answer (score 3):

Combining these two methods won't make it simpler or more efficient but you can do it.

```
private void flushGrid(Object[] grid, Object replacement) {
    for (int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < Array.getLength(grid[0]); y++) {
            Array.set(grid[x], y, replacement);
        }
    }
}
```

Note this works with primitive arrays as well as reference arrays.

Comment: You probably meant to write `Object[][] grid`? Or `(Object[]) grid[0].length`? Or even `(Object[]) grid[x].length`?

Comment: @radoh I should have changed that. You can't cast it to `Object[]` if it's a primitive array.

Comment: Oh ok, nice, didn't know about `Array.*` methods :)

Comment: @radoh add to that the `Arrays` methods :P

Comment: Yeah, I know about those ;)

Comment: @radoh at last count there is at at less half a dozen widely used of ArrayUtil ArrayUtils utility classes around in OSS library. But Array is on of the coolest.  BTW Have a look at array access in sun.misc.Unsafe

Comment: It is cool indeed. However, I would be concerned a little about performance of using `Array.*` methods, I've found a question on that topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306160/performance-of-java-lang-reflect-array Especially when using them inside the loop like this.

Comment: @radoh I agree which is why I was concerned that it "won't make it simpler or more efficient"

Comment: Ah, right, I must have missed that when I was staring at the code in amazement. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make your method generic on type `T`. Something like,

```
private <T> void flushGrid(T grid[][], T replacement) {
    for (int x = 0; x < grid.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < grid[0].length; y++) {
            grid[x][y] = replacement;
        }
    }
}
```

which would work with `String`, `Integer` or any other reference type (but not primitive types like `int`, `long` or `double`).

Comment: Generics are not supported with primitives, at least not before Java 10.

Comment: Does this means the class must be generic?

Comment: @Xoce웃Пepeúpa No, you can make a method generic without making the class generic.

Comment: This won't work for `T` == `int` as in the first example. It will only work as a replacement for the second example which is nicer but doesn't simplify anything.